# Reorder array inplace

Tags: cuda

I am working on a simulation algorithm using CUDA and have come down to the problem of removing data of an array.

I have an array, and I would like to move data, filling the holes from removed data (the end of the array will be deleted). This obviously can be done sequentially, but that is not harnessing the full power of CUDA. I would prefer this to be done in parallel.

I could do this using `thrust::scatter` and two arrays instead of one, but is it capable of doing so inplace?

Comment: Isn't what you are calling "reordering" actually stream compaction?

Answer (score 1):

Thrust has a variety of [stream compaction options](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__stream__compaction.html).  You should be able to accomplish this using `thrust::remove_if`, assuming what you want to do is remove data (only), i.e. preserving the *ordering* of the retained data.

Depending on how you have identified the items to be removed, you may use [a version that works only on the data itself](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__stream__compaction.html#ga5fa8f86717696de88ab484410b43829b) (perhaps if you have marked the items to be removed by making them negative, or zero, etc.)

Or, if you have some other vector (the "stencil") that indicates the items to be removed, [there is a version for that](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__stream__compaction.html#ga2e6f9b410f1ea32246cbb4890d636b7e) as well.

Either version operates on the supplied input vector "in place".

Here is a simple example, lifted from the thrust documentation, that uses the second "stencil" method:

```
#include <thrust/remove.h>
...
const int N = 6;
int A[N] = {1, 4, 2, 8, 5, 7};
int S[N] = {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0};
int *new_end = thrust::remove(A, A + N, S, thrust::identity<int>());
// The first three values of A are now {1, 5, 7}
// Values beyond new_end are unspecified
```

Answer (score -2):

After reading some more of thrust's source code, I was able to answer the above question as yes, it is capable of reordering an array inplace. But it is not parallel at all. In fact, it does so using a for_each, which is implemented sequentially for CUDA.

Comment: `thrust::for_each` is not implemented sequentially for CUDA